# Reading .csv file line by line

Tags: c#, string, csv

I have an excel file (.csv) which I want to read line by line or to be more precise row by row and get it stored in a string in C#
Any help is appreciated .

Comment: I suggest you do a search on SO as this has been answered many times.

Comment: A CSV is just a comma-delimited text file if that makes it easier to figure out what to do. ([hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560011/how-to-read-a-csv-file-one-line-at-a-time-and-parse-out-keywords))

Comment: @Sorceri sorry no idea what is SO , could you elaborate ?

Comment: @fOcusWow SO = Stack Overflow (see [What do SO, SF and SU stand for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114549/167646))

Comment: Pro tip: On pretty much any internet community, posting without using the search function will always result in a firestorm and down-votes where applicable. Stack Overflow even suggests related questions when you create one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should have your back;

```
var csvRows = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\demo.csv");
```

It loads each line into a new entry in a string array. (Provided that the file's EOL char is `\r\n`, and not just `\n`)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` function to `Read` all the `Lines` from the given `filepath`.

Syntax : `String [] lines= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(String filepath)`

Try This:

```
string path = @"C:\filename.csv";
String [] allLines=System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet may be helpful for you. Have a look.

```
            TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"D:\test.csv");
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(",");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Processing row
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    string test =field;
                }
            }
            parser.Close();
```

include `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as a reference.